# Why there are no graves of great devotees?

Tags: gods, bhakti

When a politician dies, we develop a park around it and the people will go to there every year on that day to memorize them.

There are some brindavanams constructed for some devotees who went on samadhi state.

But for some devotees, we even dont see their death stories like if they suffered any disease or attained samadhi but they simply disappear.

We can see the graves of great kings of 12th century also but why there are no graves for great devotees.

Some devotees I am talking about are Annamaiah, Ramadaasu etc.

Comment: Can you be specific in naming the devotees who disappear?

Comment: if he /she is grhastha no samadhi is constructed a linga is placed in frequented place like there home and worshipped.. Jagannatha dasa, Vijaya dasa and other hari dasa are having like this.. in south most people place lingam on top of samadhi even for normal people that is why its forbidden to worship any lingam except concerted temple not anyother lingam..

Comment: @Prasanna R, okay I thought like mentiined in movies, they have reached god with body so there are no graves for them

Comment: No merging of with mortal coil is allowed.. only light can merge with light.. that is god is light (Sat chit ananda roopa) Jiva in order merge ( it had to be light) not mortal coil, The mortal coil should be left behind.. Sthula sharira is burnt in the earth and the other 2 sharira (sushma and linga deha had be worn off by jiva by doing sandana in multiple(100s or 1000s or crs) of birth  to take that sushma sarira..

Comment: if a person gets moksha then noone knows except him right i.e. the stories we hear about a devotee got moksha might not be true

Comment: in case of sisupala a light emerged out of his body and went inside lord krishna.. According sri bannaje Govindacharya.. Devathas have light body which one can see.. where as all other doesnt have light as sushma sharira.. here sisupla have 2 jivas inside one is Jayantha (gatekeeper of vishnu) who is having light body. and other is Asusra hriyakashipu.. Other body none able to see because its dark in nature.. similarly general sushma body will be dark because general humans are not devatha..